# virtual machine doesn't recognise ip of the Machine it run on

Tags: bridge

I am using virtualBox to create a virtual XP machine on my XP using Bridge connection.
From my VM I am able to ping to any other IP on the network except for the IP which the VM is run on.

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Your host is running a firewall that blocks pings?